# Multer: req.file undefined/empty

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, file-upload, multer

I am trying to upload an image(part of a form) using multer on Mean Stack. However, every other data attribute is posting but I am getting undefined when it comes to image.

**html**

```html
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail1"  class="col-md-2 control-label">Club Logo</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" file-model="clubData.file">
                    </div>
               </div>
```

**routes.js**

```js
'use strict';


var joinClubTeam = require('../controllers/joinClubTeam.server.controller');
var createClub = require('../controllers/createClub.server.controller');
 // var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var multer = require('multer');
var upload =  multer({
    dest    : './uploads/',
    onError : function(err, next) {
      console.log('error', err);
      next(err);
    }
  });


module.exports = function (app) {
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  /////////////////
  // custom methods
  /////////////////
  app.route('/api/join-club-team')
    .post(joinClubTeam.JoinClubTeam);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


app.route('/api/upload', upload.single('photo')).post(createClub.TestFormData);

// 

};
```

**Server Controller.js**

```js
use strict';
 /**
  * Module dependencies
  */
var path = require('path'),
 mongoose = require('mongoose'),
 Club = mongoose.model('Club'),
 User = mongoose.model('User'),
 Player = mongoose.model('Player'),
 Team = mongoose.model('Team'),
 multer = require('multer'),
 errorHandler = require(path.resolve('./modules/core/server/controllers/errors.server.controller'));
// var upload = multer({dest: './uploads/'});


 exports.TestFormData = function(req, res,next){
  console.log('reaching here');
 console.log(req.body);
 console.log(req.file);
 res.json({success: true});
};
```

**Client Controller.js**

```js
'use strict';


angular.module('joinClubTeam').controller('createClubController', ['$scope','$state', '$http', 'Authentication', '$location', 'multipartForm', function($scope, $state, $http, Authentication, location, multipartForm){
 
         $scope.authentication = Authentication;
         $scope.clubData ={};
 

 
 $scope.LoadInitialData = function(){

  
  $http.get('api/sports').success(function(response){
   $scope.AllSports = response;
   
   console.log(response);
   $scope.selectedSportId = response[0]._id;
   
  });
  
 };

 
 $scope.submit = function(){

  console.log($scope.clubData.file.name);
  
   // var uploadUrl = '/upload';
  multipartForm.post('/api/upload', $scope.clubData);

 };
 
 
 
 
 
}




]);
```

***Using Custom Directive and a service.***
***Most guidelines are followed using this tut ***
https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs

Comment: Do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set in your `<form>` element?

Comment: @mscdex Yes enctype=multipart/form-data. Didn't post it here because there were other form components as well

Comment: @mscdex Also the file is successfully posted from the client side.

Answer (score 1):

I found that using `multer` alongside `bodyParser` can cause `req.file` to be undefined. Make sure to check that also if you're having issues.

You also need to make sure the `name="filename"` and `upload.single(filename)` matches.